# Show checkbox as checked when value matches php

Tags: php, zend-framework

Retriving the roles of user using user id

```
$userId = $userDetails['user_id'];
$stmt = $db->query ( "SELECT user_role_id FROM user_role_xref where user_id=" . $userId);
$userRoles = $stmt->fetchAll ();
print_r($userRoles);
```

When i print this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [user_role_id] => 3 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [user_role_id] => 4 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [user_role_id] => 5 ) 
    )
```

how to show check box as checked when value matches else checkbox is unchecked

```
<input type="checkbox" id="roles_1" value="3" name="roles[]" />
<label for="roles_1">Role1</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="roles_2" value="4" name="roles[]" />
<label for="roles_2">Role2</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="roles_3" value="5" name="roles[]" /> 
<label for="roles_3">Role3</label><br/>
```

Comment: are you using Zend_Form?

Comment: er, that doesn't answer my question. Zend_Db is not Zend_Form. Are you using Zend_Form?

Answer (score 1):

HTML attribute `checked="checked"`.

E.g:

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if ($var) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> id="roles_2" value="4" name="roles[]" />
```

Comment: how i can check $var directly?

Comment: Don't know what the question is, but you might mean this: `if ($userRoles[0]['user_role_id'] == 2) echo...`

Answer (score 0):

Use in_array function of php
Check if the value exists or not
If it exists then set checked property otherwise display unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("roles_1",$roles_array){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> id="roles_1" value="1" name="roles[]" />
```